# how to control process that killed

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, monitoring

we want to know what are the options to control processes ,

**for example**

```
/opt/important_script/gate_machine.pl
```

is a script that must be up and running

and in case from some reason script killed , then we must to start it again

I was thinking to use some cron job under `/etc/cron.d`

and use it for this purpose ,

and every min check if PID is alive if not then cron job will start the script again

but I want to know about more options about this

Comment: If you're using a distro with `systemd`, just write a service file for your process, and have `systemd` manage it: https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Comment: I was thinking that if we start the service and it fails then service will restart it , but what isn't clear that if for example I will kill the pid , the do you think the service will restart ?

Comment: Yes, if you specifiy `Restart=always` `systemd` would restart your service regardless of the reason for which it died. The only way to properly stop it would be `systemctl stop <service>`.